# Hide navigation bar with table view

Tags: swift, navigation, tableview, hide

I'm trying to hide navigation bar when I scroll my table view. It seems that when I scroll inside table view this one can't detect the scrolling event.. when I scroll outside table view navigation bar get hidden...how can I resolve ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the navigation controller hideBarsOnSwipe to true

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}
```

Comment: are you sure your view controller is embedded inside a UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes my view controller is embedded inside a UINavigationController and has inside a tableview. If i swap don't touching tableview it works...but i want my tableview to have full dimension of view...